# SQL Server - Enabling FileStream after a DB has been created

Tags: sql-server

We have a database and have decided to enable it for FileStream use. I think I've done everything I'm supposed to except creating a FileStream Data Container. I can't seem to find a way to do this in SSMS 2008 on our existing database. Can this only be done at the time a database is created?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To add FS support to existing database just create a new filegroup, then add the fs file;

```
alter database YourDatabase
add filegroup fsGroup contains filestream;
go

alter database YourDatabase
add file
  ( NAME = 'fsYourDatabase', FILENAME = 'c:\<your_file_path>'
   )
to filegroup fsGroup;
go
```

More here: [BOL Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx)

And definitely read everything Paul Randal has written about filestream:  [link](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/filestream/)

Comment: For The c:\<your_file_path> the last part of the path must not exist eg C:\data\filestreamdata . Data must exist but filestreamdata not

Comment: Here is an updated link to Paul Randal's blog: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/filestream/

Answer (score 10):

### From http://brianseekford.com/wordpress/?p=509

---

If you still get `FILESTREAM feature is disabled.` check the 'running values' of your server and you'll probably still see it is disabled even if you enabled it.

[image]

You can fix it by enabling filestream here too (under Sql configuration manager).

[image]

Then you need to run

> EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
>
> RECONFIGURE

Comment: Hey there, it is a bit of time gone, but I acutally have a question for the FileStream configuration. Do I have to use the SQL configuration manager to make it work or is there a work around for it?